# getting error when invoking C# method From XSLT

Tags: c#, xslt, visual-studio-2012, xslt-2.0, saxon

Got this error **"Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named {urn:rend-scripts}GetImageString().**” when invoking C# Method GetImageString(String) from XSLT using Saxon9ee Processor. please help me how to resolve this.

Code:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:xpp="http://www.sdl.com/xpp"  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:rend="urn:rend-scripts" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xpp msxsl rend">
 <msxsl:script language="c#" implements-prefix="rend">
 <msxsl:assembly href="C:\Users\velagasx\Desktop\dll4rtf\System.IO.dll"/>
 <msxsl:assembly href="C:\Users\velagasx\Desktop\dll4rtf\System.Drawing.dll"/>
 <msxsl:using namespace="System.IO"/>
 <msxsl:using namespace="System.Drawing"/>    
 <![CDATA[
    public string GetImageString(String path_to_image){
      MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
      Image img = Image.FromFile(path_to_image);
      img.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff);
      byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();
      string output = BitConverter.ToString(bytes, 0).Replace("-", string.Empty);          
      return output;
      }
    ]]>
```

```
    <xsl:template match="img">
       <xsl:value-of select="rend:GetImageString(@path)"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

thanks

Srinadh

Comment: is this just a typing issue? Does it work with `"rend:GetImageString('somethingFixed')"` ? It could be you need to either a: convert the `@path` to a string before passing it in (maybe the `text()` function?), or b: have the method accept an `XPathNodeIterator`

Answer (score 1):

`msxsl:script` in the namespace `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt` is a proprietary extension element, originally supported by the various Microsoft MSXML versions, then enhanced with `msxsl:assembly` and `msxsl:using` for the Microsoft `XslCompiledTransform`. I don't think Saxon supports that extension element. If you want to use extensions with Saxon check http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!extensibility/dotnetextensions.

Comment: Correct, Saxon's approach to calling C# methods is quite different from Microsoft's. There's no standard in this area.